# How to get variable name? - java

Tags: java

is possible get variable name?

For example:

```
String nameOfCar = "audi";
```

Now print the result:

```
System.out.println(nameOfCar.getVname???or something similar);
```

Screen:

```
nameOfCar
```

Comment: What for do you need it?

Comment: Why not just use `"nameOfCar"`?

Comment: In Java, variable names are only available at compile time. They are not available when you run your program.

Comment: @KorayTugay Of course it's possible. Reflection is there for a reason. (It's just slow.)

Comment: @TheLostMind Oh, sorry, then it isn't possible. I was thinking that the OP was talking about a field of a class.

Comment: So it is not like Python, variable.__name__. However, if you use mapping structure and store it inside statically, then you can display the variable name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get all field name by reflection

```
Class yourClass = YourClass.class
Field[] fields = yourClass.getFields();
for(Field f: fields){
    f.getName();
}
```

or if you want mapping then go for Map

```
Map<String, String> propertyToValueMap
```

if you are trying to read method's local variable name, then it is not that simple to fetch also a signal that you are doing something wrong

Comment: Please say something about method-variables too.

Comment: In order to access Private Fields, use 'yourClass.getDeclaredFields()'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via reflection

```
Class  myClass = MyClass.class
Field field = myClass.getField("nameOfCar ");
System.out.println(field .getName());
```

To get all the fields without using the name you can do

```
Field[] myFields = myClass .getFields();
```

Comment: lookup field name by field name to get field name ?

Comment: You will get the `Field Object`. As per OP he can use the field name `nameOfCar.getVname`.