# How to Log event Data by only changing the Json method?

Tags: android, json, logging

I have an Android Application.

I have captured the events by creating a method which captures various parameter /variable value from the application.
The code snippet which I have written contain EventClass and EventModelClass
{
public class UserAccessEvent implements ILog {

```
private Logger mLogger = null;
UserAccessEventModel obj;

public void StoreUserAccessEvent(String Timestamp, String UserId, int FailedAttempts, int SuccessfulAttempts, int Attempts,
                                 int NoOfRevocations, int PassCodeChange) {

    obj = new UserAccessEventModel(Timestamp, UserId,  SuccessfulAttempts, FailedAttempts, Attempts, NoOfRevocations, PassCodeChange);

    toJsonLog();
}

public String toJsonLog() {

    JSONObject event = new JSONObject();

    try {

        event.put("Timestamp", obj.getTimestamp());
        event.put("UserId", obj.userid);
        event.put("SuccessfulAttempts", obj.successfulattempts);
        event.put("FailedAttempts", obj.failedattempts);
        event.put("Attempts", obj.attempts);
        event.put("NoOfRevocations", obj.noofrevocations);
        event.put("PassCodeChange", obj.passcodechange);

        //to store the log data that is stored in json object
        Log.d("UserAccessEvent", event.toString());
        return event.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("UserAccessEvent", "Exception");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}
```

}

public class UserAccessEventModel {

```
private String timestamp;
public String userid;
public int successfulattempts;
public int failedattempts;
public int attempts;
public int noofrevocations;
public int passcodechange;


public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public void setSuccessfulattempts(int successfulattempts) { this.successfulattempts = successfulattempts;   }

public void setFailedattempts(int failedattempts) {
    this.failedattempts = failedattempts;
}

public void setAttempts(int attempts) {
    this.attempts = attempts;
}

public void setNoofrevocations(int noofrevocations) {
    this.noofrevocations = noofrevocations;
}

public void setPasscodechange(int passcodechange) {
    this.passcodechange = passcodechange;
}

public String getTimestamp(){
    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return timestamp;

}

public UserAccessEventModel() {

}

public UserAccessEventModel(String timestamp, String userid, int successfulattempts, int failedattempts, int attempts, int noofrevocations, int passcodechange) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.successfulattempts = successfulattempts;
    this.failedattempts = failedattempts;
    this.attempts = attempts;
    this.noofrevocations = noofrevocations;
    this.passcodechange = passcodechange;
}
```

}

I want to make changes so that I can just use JSON to log data without using model class.I want it to be more generic.....

Now I need to log the data which is in the method by just changing the JSON method key/values pair.

Is there any method where I can do this??

Please Give any Suggestions.

Comment: can you put some code? What you have tried?

Comment: @Megha Maniar I have posted the code which i have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 you can do as following.

```
public String toJsonLog(Class YourModelClass) {
                JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
                Class yourClass = YourModelClass.class;
                Field[] fields = yourClass.getFields();

                YourModelClass obj = new YourModelClass();

                for(Field f: fields){
                    f.getName();
                }
                try {
                    for(int i=0; i<fields.length(); i++){
                    String geterStr = obj + ".get" + fields[i] + "()";
                        event.put(fields[i], geterStr);
                    }

                    Log.d("YourModelClass", event.toString());
                    return event.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("YourModelClass", "Exception");
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);

                }
            }
```

but in this you have to make getter method same as your field name. for ex. say your field name is `userId` then you have to make getter method as `getuserId()` instead of `getUserId()`. you have to ignore java naming convention to make this generic.

**Note:** I haven't tried this, but I took reference from this question: [How to get variable name? - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710487/how-to-get-variable-name-java) and put my own logic, but I guess it should work.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Do we have any solution using Factory method?