# Use log4j to print variable name java

Tags: java, variables, logging, reflection, log4j

is it possible to print a variable name using log4j?

I want to achieve something like:

`SomeObject someName = 123;`

`log.info("The variable: " + someName.getMyName() + " was used.");`

and get result:
The variable: someName was used.

ps I do not have access to the object.

Comment: Do you instrument the code? Has the code debug information compiled into it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710487/how-to-get-variable-name-java